# Can a broken cdrom drive cause I/O errors in programs like dd, ddrescue, etc.?

Tags: dvd, dd, compact-disc, ddrescue

Can a broken cdrom drive cause I/O errors in programs like dd, ddrescue, etc. even if the disc itself doesn't contain bad sectors?

Note that I'm interested in purely technical, factual answers, not personal opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If data is unable to get from the device to the processor - for any reason (for a recognised/specified block device) it should cause errors for ddrescue/the kernel.  This is true for cabling errors, general hardware errors and errors on the disk that the drive does not conceal when communicating with the interface.

It might be worth expounding your problem and drive type for better targetted answers.